# CornerRadius issue with GeometryReader in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a small red Rec inside GeometryReader, if I use cornerRadius on GeometryReader it will going crop the Rec, which I do not want it. See the deference in photos:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { _ in
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .position(x: 0, y: 0)
            
            
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        .cornerRadius(10)      // <<: Here try comment and uncomment it to see the result!

        
    }
}
```

without cornerRadius:

[image]

with cornerRadius:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the yellow to have the corner radius and to not crop the red square, give the corner radius to only the background:

```
.background(
            Color.yellow
                .cornerRadius(10)
        )
```

If you want the red square to have a corner radius as well but not be cropped, give it a corner radius as well:

```
Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .position(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Giving the GeometryReader itself a corner radius is not something that I would expect to have straightforward results, since the GeometryReader itself is not rendered per say (or at least rendered like we normally think of visual components), but as we can see from your example, it's basically treated like a container view -- giving it a corner radius ends up cropping out everything outside the bounds of it's content minus the corner radius.